# I can not deal with the class Application and add a method to it

Tags: android

I'm trying to deal with the class Application.I found an example of its creation.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  private static MyApplication singleton;
  public static MyApplication getInstance() {
  return singleton;
}
@Override
public final void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  singleton = this;
   }
}
```

but I do not understand how to use it. I have a class Events:

```
public class Events {
    public static final Bus BUS = new Bus();
}
```

I use so:

```
Events.BUS.register(this);
Events.BUS.post(weatherResponse);
```

I need to get rid of class `Event` and move everything in the class `MyApplication`

I do not know how to do it, then how to access the class bus and how it all works

Answer (score 0):

1.Modify `AndroidManifest.xml` , in `application` label

```
<application
    android:name="yourpackagename.MyApplication"
    ...
    >
</application>
```

2.Remove `Events` class, and declare `Bus` in `MyApplication`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

  public static final Bus BUS = new Bus();
  private static MyApplication singleton;

  public static MyApplication getInstance() {
    return singleton;
  }

  @Override
  public final void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    singleton = this;
    Events.BUS.register(this);
    Events.BUS.post(weatherResponse);
   }
}
```